# Can I safely power on my Moto G2 LTE without the camera hw module?

Tags: battery, camera, hardware

I have recently dropped my phone and the flashlight and camera suddenly stopped to work. I suppose this is an hw failure, so I have ordered a new module.
Meanwhile I noticed a huge battery drain (-25%) in the night (normally is 1-2%). I would like to remove the module before the package arrives.